# Can't write data from array to selected range

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm a newbie at Google Apps Script and trying to make a simple script: it should multiply numbers in selected range by three:

```js
function myfunction(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var dataArray = sheet.getActiveRange().getValues(); 
  for (i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++){
    dataArray[i] = dataArray[i] * 3;  
  };
  Logger.log (dataArray);
  sheet.getActiveRange().setValues([dataArray]);  
};
```

When I try to run this script, it gives me next error: "The number of rows in the array doesn't match the number of rows in the range." The problem is in this line:

```js
sheet.getActiveRange().setValues([dataArray]);
```

And I can't find and figure out, where is my mistake.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you need a script for that? If you are just experimenting with Apps Script, I'm sorry but sometimes folks write a hundred lines of code for something that can be done with one formula, e.g. =ArrayFormula(range*3)

Comment: I'd still prefer the hundred of code.

Comment: Yeah, I'm justt experimenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myfunction(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var dataArray = sheet.getActiveRange().getValues(); 
  for (i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++){
    for(var j=0;j<dataArray[i].length;j++) {
      dataArray[i][j] = dataArray[i][j] * 3;  
    }
  }
  Logger.log (dataArray);
  sheet.getActiveRange().setValues(dataArray);  
}
```